# Application does not run in background simply does not work

Tags: ios

I have read over many stack overflow questions where people ask to terminate their app oppose to let it run in the background.

The main answer I found was to set the application does not run in background BOOL to YES in my info.plist

I have done this and cleaned my project but still my application runs in the background when the user presses the home button. This solution simply does not work.

What can I do to make my application quit when a user presses the home button.

My app is currently running on iOS 6.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: The main reason why I am trying to do this and not support the background thread is because I can't get my iPod view controller to stop playing music when the application enters the background. 

I can stop the music if the user enters the background in my iPod view but I can't if they are in any other view which is super annoying.

Comment: Are you sure you set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to type boolean in info.plist, not a string?

Comment: UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend does not exist. It is now Application does not run in background. 

And yes the value is set to type BOOL not string.

Comment: This is really weird behavior

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for your first comment, not the original question. Have your iPod view controller register for the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification. The implementation should stop the music. This is a much better user experience than choosing to have your app terminate on suspend.

```
// Put this in a good place like viewDidLoad 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(backgrounding) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

// Handle the notification
- (void)backgrounding {
    // app is leaving the foreground, stop the music
}

// In your dealloc method add:
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: If I add the observer in the viewDidLoad for my iPod View Controller wont it only work if the user exits the app from my iPod View Controller? 

like if they switch to another view then technically backgrounding would never get called...

Or am I just flat out wrong?

Comment: The view controller will get the notification as long as the view controller is loaded. If you push another view controller or display another modal view controller, it will still get notified. But if you totally dismiss the view controller such that it is deallocated, then of course it won't be notified. But I would have to assume that at the point the music isn't playing anymore anyway.

Comment: Well in my app a user and type in lyrics to a song... 

then they can press on the iPod view controller to play a song. Currently when they switch back to the lyric view they can  play the song so it streams in a karaoke view with the music playing in the background.

So normally if it was just an iPod view i would want the music to stop but in my case I want it to continue when they are in the lyric view. 

So when they leave the lyric view is when I prompt the user to stop the music but I just can't seem to get the music to stop when im in the lyric view.